# Mutating the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

> For the following question, the function
>
> • should mutate the original list
>
> • should NOT create any new lists
>
> • should NOT return anything
>
> Functions that do not create new lists are said to be ”in place.” Such functions are often desirable because they do not require extra memory to operate.
>
> Implement the function map_mut, which applies a function fn onto every element of
> a list called lst.

```
def map_mut(fn, lst):
"""Maps fn onto lst by mutation.
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> map_mut(lambda x: x**2, lst)
>>> lst
[1, 4, 9, 16]
"""
*** Your code here***
```

Below is the solution:

```
def map_mut(fn, lst):
    """Maps fn onto lst by mutation.

    >>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    >>> map_mut(lambda x: x**2, lst)
    >>> lst
    [1, 4, 9, 16]
    """
    def mutate(index):
        if len(lst) == index:
            return
        else:
            lst[index] = fn(lst[index])
            return mutate(index + 1)
    return mutate(0)
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
map_mut(lambda x: x**2, lst)
```

Can we improve this solution in recursive approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eliminate the tail recursion. [Python does not optimize tail calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion) so the recursion costs O(N) stack memory. You can achieve the requirements with a simple loop.

Your recursive solution could be expressed more concisely. Functions return `None` if they do not otherwise return a value.

```
def mutate(index):
    if index < len(lst):
        lst[index] = fn(lst[index])
        mutate(index + 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your solution is too complicated.  I would also say that it is not idiomatic Python, since it's using a weird technique to perform simple iteration.  The problem does not call for a recursive approach, so you should not use recursion here.

```
def map_mut(fn, lst):
    """(docstring here)"""
    for index, value in enumerate(lst):
        lst[index] = fn(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

**You got the tests, what about running them?**

It is useful to automatically run your tests, just

```
import doctest

# code

doctest.testmod()
```

### As simple as possible

You are using closures and recursion and other mind-bending stuff while the function could be written:

```
def map_mut(fn, lst):
    """Maps fn onto lst by mutation.

    >>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    >>> map_mut(lambda x: x**2, lst)
    >>> lst
    [1, 4, 9, 16]
    """
    for index in range(len(lst)):
        lst[index] = fn(lst[index])
```

Comment: Canyou make my code recursively more elegant without closure?let me think of performance issues later.

Comment: yes I ran the test

Comment: There's no need to `import doctest` as you can run doctests from the command line using `python -m doctest myprogram.py`.