# Inverse mapping of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash-map

For the below question picked from [here](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa12/disc/disc4.pdf):

> Write `make_inverse_dict(d)` that returns a new dictionary with the
>   'inverse' mapping. The 'inverse' mapping of a dictionary `d` is a new
>   dictionary that maps each of `d`'s values to all keys in `d` that
>   mapped to it. For instance:
>
> ```
> >>> d1 = {'call': 3, 'me': 2, 'maybe': 3}
> >>> d2 = make_inverse_dict(d1)
> >>> d2  # note that we know nothing about the order of dictionaries
> {3: ('maybe', 'call'), 2: ('me',)}
> ```
>
> The ordering of the tuple of keys doesn't matter, i.e., `d2` could
>   have instead been `{3: ('call', 'maybe'), 2: ('me',)}`.

Below is the solution:

```
d1 = {'me': 2, 'call': 3, 'may be': 3}

def make_inverse_dict(d1):
    d2 = {}
    for key in d1:
        if d2.get(d1[key]) == None:
           d2[d1[key]] = (key,)
        else:
            d2[d1[key]] += (key,)
    return d2

d2 = make_inverse_dict(d1)
```

Additionally this is the recursive solution:

```
d1 = {'me': 2, 'call': 3, 'may be': 3} 
def isEmpty(dictionary):
    for element in dictionary:
        if element:
            return False
    return True


def make_inverse_dict_recur(d1):
    temp = {}
    def make_inverse_dict():
        if not isEmpty(d1):
            tup = d1.popitem()
            if temp.get(tup[1]) == None:
                temp[tup[1]] = (tup[0], )
            else:
                temp[tup[1]] += (tup[0], )          
            make_inverse_dict()
    make_inverse_dict()
    return temp

d2 = make_inverse_dict_recur(d1.copy())
```

Can we improve these solutions?

Comment: (Deleted my answer, as it was misleading. -- sorry :))  In general, try to use list comprehensions and generators if you can.  There are some interesting utilities in the `itertools` package that might help you.

Comment: For more speed and readability, don't iterate over just the keys, iterate over keys and values at the same time `for key, value in dict.items()` or `for key, value in dict.iteritems()` (Python2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the recursive approach, using a nested function, is a bit awkward. I tend to avoid reliance on closures ([*"explicit is better than implicit"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), after all!) and use explicit parameters instead.

---

To create a `temp` dictionary only on the top level call, I would use:

```
def recur_func(..., temp=None):
    if temp is None:
        temp = {}
    ...
    recur_func(..., temp)
```

*(if you're wondering why not `temp={}` in the parameter list, see ["“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761))*

---

Rather than `tup = d1.popitem()` then indexing into the tuple, I would use `key, val = d1.popitem()`; this improves the readability of subsequent lines, as e.g. `key` is much more informative than `tup[0]`. You can also use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) (or, as pointed out in [Günther's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90038/32391), [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)) to neaten up the logic:

```
key, val = d1.popitem()
temp.setdefault(val, []).append(key)
```

---

That just leaves factoring out the nested function, and making `make_inverse_dict_recur` directly recursive:

```
def make_inverse_dict_recur(d1, temp=None):
    if temp is None:
        temp = {}
    if not isEmpty(d1):  # why not just 'if d1:'?
        key, val = d1.popitem()
        temp.setdefault(val, []).append(key)        
        make_inverse_dict_recur(d1, temp)
    return temp
```

---

[Again](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88764/32391), though, contrast that with the iterative version:

```
def make_inverse_dict_iter(d1):
    temp = {}
    for key, val in d1.items():
        temp.setdefault(val, []).append(key)
    return temp
```

This has the neat advantage of *not* mutating `d1`; generally, Python functions should either mutate their arguments **or** return a new object, not both. I suspect that this would be (at best) tricky to achieve with a recursive approach, though.

Comment: What does `if d1:` do? the same work that `isEmpty(d1)` does?

Comment: @overexchange not quite; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- Iterate over dictionaries using `for key, value in d.items()` (or `iteritems()` in Python2.
- Consider using a `collections.defaultdict(list)` as output dictionary.
  Then you can append unconditionally.
- When appending to arrays, don't use `d += (key,)`, but just `d.append(key)`.
- Try looking into the `itertools` package.  This one has interesting combinators for generators that can make your code very concise.
- Prefer list and dict comprehensions if you can.

Comment: how do I think of recursive approach for the same?

Comment: i think `d.extend(key)` is better than `d.append(key)`

Comment: `extend` and `append` do different things; `append` only adds one item, `extend` appends another list (or more generally, a sequence) at the end.

Comment: `extend` will be a problem if `isinstance(key, str) and len(key) > 1`, for example...